# Google Api, Node.js - invalid_grant Malformed auth code

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-authentication

I'm trying to use the google api on node.js, but I always have the following error:

```
invalid_grant
Malformed auth code
```

By searching on the web I saw that the client id should be an email address, not the client id on the console. I changed that to the email address of my google account, it was even worse because I wasn't able to connect using google

Here's the code, adapted from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var { google } = require('googleapis');
// var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/google-apis-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'google-apis-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  //See full code sample for authorize() function code.
authorize(JSON.parse(content), {'params': {'id': 'Ks-_Mh1QhMc',
                 'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics'}}, videosListById);

});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, requestData, callback) {
  // Regarder response.config.data
  var clientSecret = credentials.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.redirect_uri;
  var auth = google.auth.OAuth2;
  var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    redirectUrl
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, requestData, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client, requestData);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, requestData, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token');
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client, requestData);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Remove parameters that do not have values.
 *
 * @param {Object} params A list of key-value pairs representing request
 *                        parameters and their values.
 * @return {Object} The params object minus parameters with no values set.
 */
function removeEmptyParameters(params) {
  for (var p in params) {
    if (!params[p] || params[p] == 'undefined') {
      delete params[p];
    }
  }
  return params;
}

/**
 * Create a JSON object, representing an API resource, from a list of
 * properties and their values.
 *
 * @param {Object} properties A list of key-value pairs representing resource
 *                            properties and their values.
 * @return {Object} A JSON object. The function nests properties based on
 *                  periods (.) in property names.
 */
function createResource(properties) {
  var resource = {};
  var normalizedProps = properties;
  for (var p in properties) {
    var value = properties[p];
    if (p && p.substr(-2, 2) == '[]') {
      var adjustedName = p.replace('[]', '');
      if (value) {
        normalizedProps[adjustedName] = value.split(',');
      }
      delete normalizedProps[p];
    }
  }
  for (var p in normalizedProps) {
    // Leave properties that don't have values out of inserted resource.
    if (normalizedProps.hasOwnProperty(p) && normalizedProps[p]) {
      var propArray = p.split('.');
      var ref = resource;
      for (var pa = 0; pa < propArray.length; pa++) {
        var key = propArray[pa];
        if (pa == propArray.length - 1) {
          ref[key] = normalizedProps[p];
        } else {
          ref = ref[key] = ref[key] || {};
        }
      }
    };
  }
  return resource;
}

function videosListById(auth, requestData) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  var parameters = removeEmptyParameters(requestData['params']);
  parameters['auth'] = auth;
  service.videos.list(parameters, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
```

I literally copy-paste the code in the console, but still have the same error

Answer (score 13):

Here is my case:

The authorization code in the url hash fragment is being encoded by `encodeURIComponent` API, so if you pass this code to request the access token. It will throw an error:

`{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed auth code." }`

So I use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) to decode the authorization code.

```
decodeURIComponent('4%2F_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY')
```

After decode, the authorization code is:

```
"4/_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY"
```

Comment: the same issue was solved in iOS. just with decoding URL components!

Answer (score 0):

Generally the URL is Encoded, So **decode the URL** and try again

Try URL Encode/Decode Tool [click here](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

In python it can be done as below:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote
# Decode the url
query_str  = unquote(request.META.get('QUERY_STRING'))
 # Or just decode CODE
code = unquote(code)
data_dict = {
        "code": code, "redirect_uri":"", "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "client_id": "","client_secret": ""
}
resp = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data_dict)
```