# How to use refresh and access token obtianed using Oauth playground to call People API in my Google Action?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-authentication, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to access the contacts of authenticated user .
I have got the refresh and access token from oauth playground.
How do I use these tokens to call people's api?

Comment: Do you have the client id and the client secret?

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you can show specific code that you are using, or a specific problem that you have been trying to solve, but that you need help in debugging the problem. Open-ended questions such as these are much more difficult. If you can show us what you've tried so far, or what,specifically, you're having problems with, we have a better chance of helping you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes i do have a client id and secret @ziganotschka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your case probably the easiest is to create an authentification flow as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs), whereby you hardcode the `token.json` file yourself.**

- If you run  the sample code from the quickstart without having a `token.json` file, you will be redirected to an authorization URL where you have to authenticate with your account, so that a token file with your credentials will be created.
- However, if you already have a token file for a user, you do not need to authorize the app by signing in as the given user.
- The structure of a `token.json` file is the following:

```
{"access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","refresh_token":"YYYYYYYYYY","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ZZZZZZZZZ","token_type":"Bearer","expiry_date":UNIX TIMESTAMP IN SECONDS}
```

- If you possess the required information nothing stops you from creating a `token.json` file yourself

**Alternatively**

- Create an `oauth2Client` as described in the documentation for [Authentication and authorization with OAuth2](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client) and use the method

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: 'STORED_REFRESH_TOKEN'
});
```

to assign to the `oauth2Client` a refresh token manually.

Comment: I have followed the documentation to create an authentication flow, after authorizing the app , when i enter the code, I get the following error:  { error: 'invalid_grant',
      error_description: 'Malformed auth code.' }

Comment: Have you decoded the token? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54878799/11599789). There can be also other problems, e.g. user did not grant you offline access or revoked access, have a look at the [possible scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google).